# Do PySpark window functions affect the write operation?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am having trouble writing a PySpark dataframe (~50 columns and ~9 million rows) to an S3 bucket, and I have isolated the problem, though I am not sure why the problem occurs.

The following runs quite quickly (< 1 minute):

```
# Runs < 1 minute
df.write.format('parquet') \
    .option("escape", "\"")\
    .option('header', 'true') \
    .mode('overwrite') \
    .save("s3://userName/folderName")
```

However, if I perform the following steps, then the write doesn’t finish (i.e., it just "hangs" for hours)?

```
window1 = Window.partitionBy("state")\
    .orderBy(F.col("date").cast('timestamp').cast('long'))\
    .rangeBetween(-100,0)

df = df.withColumn('new_variable', F.avg(F.col('binary_variable_01')).over(window1))

df.count()

# Runs for hours after running the window funciton
df.write.format('parquet') \
    .option("escape", "\"")\
    .option('header', 'true') \
    .mode('overwrite') \
    .save("s3://userName/folderName")
```

Here is what I have tried:

1. Repartitioning to correct for data skew didn’t work (i.e. df = df.repartition(50))
2. Coalesce to correct for data skew also didn’t work (i.e. df = df.coalesce(50))
3. Missing values in the partitionBy variable (i.e., "state" above) were imputed, but this didn’t solve the issue.
4. Created a random partition variable (50 random values) and then repartitioned based on this; didn’t work.

Does anyone have an idea as to how to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you try df.repartition(50, col("state")), also how many cores you have for all executos, also can you post the result of df.groupBy("state").count().orderBy(col("count").desc).show(false)

Comment: 1) Trying df.repartition(50,F.col("state")); 2) I have 12 cores for 12 instances, so 144 and 3) I cannot show the result of df.groupBy("state")....., but I can say that it is very unbalanced.

Comment: Then try df.repartition(432,F.col("state")) instead, repartition should be 2x or 3x the number of executors also make sure is called before .withColumn('new_variable', F.avg(F

Comment: Also try to drop the rows with null values as they may have impact in your data df.dropna("state") and see the results